# How to integrate AlertDialog with Navigation component in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-architecture-navigation, jetpack-compose-navigation, navigation-compose

I am using Jetpack Compose and the Android navigation component. When I am on a screen with an `AlertDialog`, I am unable to navigate back. I guess it's due to the `AlertDialog` catching the back button event. However I don't know how to connect the `AlertDialog` to the navigation component? Is there any official way or best practice to do this? Here's my code:

```
// sample with a screen and a "navigate to dialog" button.
// once the button is pressed, an AlertDialog is shown.
// Using the back button while the AlertDialog is open has no effect ):    

@Composable
fun MyNavHost(navController: NavHostController, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = "start_route",
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        composable("start_route") {
            Text("start screen")
        }
        
        // this is my screen with the dialog
        dialog("dialog_route") {
            AlertDialog(
                onDismissRequest = {  /*TODO*/ }, // guess I need to connect this to the navigation component? bug how?
                title = {
                    Text(text = "Dialog title")
                },
                text = {
                    Text(text = "I am a dialog")
                },
                buttons = {}
            )
        }
    }
}


class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            MyJetpackComposeTheme {
                val navController = rememberNavController()

                Scaffold() { innerPadding ->

                    Column {
                        Button(onClick = { navController.navigate("dialog_route") }) {
                            Text("navigate to dialog")
                        }
                        MyNavHost(navController, modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! I'm not sure if this will help you, but there is a good Jetpack Compose navigation library called "Jetmagic". Here's a link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70575813/11004423 Maybe this library will work better for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per [the `dialog` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/navigation/compose/package-summary#(androidx.navigation.NavGraphBuilder).dialog(kotlin.String,kotlin.collections.List,kotlin.collections.List,androidx.compose.ui.window.DialogProperties,kotlin.Function1)):

> This is suitable only when this dialog represents a separate screen in your app that needs its own lifecycle and saved state, independent of any other destination in your navigation graph. **For use cases such as `AlertDialog`, you should use those APIs directly in the `composable` destination that wants to show that dialog.**

So you shouldn't be using a `dialog` destination at all: a `dialog` destination is specifically and only for providing the `content` lambda of a regular [`Dialog`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/window/package-summary#Dialog(kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.window.DialogProperties,kotlin.Function0)). What your code is actually doing is creating an empty `Dialog` (i.e., you don't emit any composables in the lambda you pass to `dialog`, then creating another `AlertDialog` stacked on top of that empty `dialog`. That's not what you want to be doing.

Instead, you should be [following the `AlertDialog` docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#AlertDialog(kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.window.DialogProperties)) and directly creating the `AlertDialog` where you want it to be used, setting your own boolean for when it should be shown/hidden.

Comment: do you know how solve this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72609914/11560810)